# Access class property passed as generic type

Tags: c#, class, generics, generic-type-argument

I have two classes, which are passed to Serialization method and I would like to access two properties of these classes in Serialization method. The problem is that Serialization method parameter are passed as generic type and I do not know how to access properties of passed class in this case. The example below.

```
    public class MyClass1 
    {

            public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

            //These properties are shared in both classes
            public bool Result { get; set; }
            public string EngineErrorMessage { get; set; }

    }
    public class MyClass2 
    {

            public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }

            //These properties are shared in both classes
            public bool Result { get; set; }
            public string EngineErrorMessage { get; set; }

    }


//The method is used to serialize classes above, classes are passed as generic types
    public void Serialization<T>(ref T engine)
            {
                try
                {
                 //Do some work with passed class
                 }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                   //If Exception occurs I would like to write values to passed class properties, how to do that?
                   Result = false;
                   EngineErrorMessage = e.Message;
                }
    }
```

Full method code

```
     public void Submit<T>(ref T engine)
        {
            try
            {

                var workingDir = Path.Combine(Settings.FileStoragePath, Helpers.GetRandomInt(9).ToString());



                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDir);
                var inputFile = Path.Combine(workingDir, Settings.InFileName);
                var outputFile = Path.Combine(workingDir, Settings.OutFileName);
                var deleteFile = Path.Combine(workingDir, Settings.DelFileName);

                try
                {



                    using (var stream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        Serializer.Serialize(stream, engine);
                    }


                    CheckStatus(outputFile);


                    using (var stream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        engine = Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);                        
                    }


                }
                finally
                {
                    File.Create(deleteFile).Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //ToDo: Not implemented yet.
/*               Result = false;
               ErrorMessage = e.Message;*/
            }
        }
```

Comment: Btw, it seems very unlikely that you would need `ref` on a method that serializes a class... is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: I am new to C# and use your serialization library, I use serialization and desiarialiaztion in one method. The code above is not the whole. So to desializate and return values back to class I pass it as ref. Also if I will not pass class as reference I will not be able to assign Result and EngineErrorMessage properties of these classes. Right?

Comment: @Tomas even without the `ref` you are still passing a reference to the instance (since it is a class), so `.Result` and `EngineErrorMessage` will still work fine; the real question is whether you need to *assign a new object* to the parameter *and have the caller notice the reassignment*. However, in most cases it would be preferable to `return` such a value, for example `void Serialize(T)` and `T Deserialize()`.

Comment: @Marc I have posted full method code, as you see I am not only serialize class but also desiarialize it. If I remove REF the code below will not work. Right?
engine = Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, this will not work without `ref`. As Marc said just return `engine`.

Comment: @Tomas indeed. It seems a slightly odd usage, but as long as makes sense in your system, fine. (it also *looks* odd that you *write* the the `inputFile` and *read* from the `outputFile`, but again: as long as it all makes sense I'm happy). Returning the new instance (`return engine`) would work too, of course.

Comment: Thank you Marc and Florian, the problem is solved! Stackoverflow is good place to ask for dev help when there are so many smart peoples here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an interface containing the properties `Result` and `EngineErrorMessage`. Now you have two options:

1. Add a constraint to your serialization type parameter so that only types that derive from the interface mentioned above can be serialized, or
2. In your catch block try to cast `engine` to the interface mentioned above. If the cast succeeds, write the propertie values, otherwise do nothing.

Sample:

```
public interface ISerializationErrorWriter
{
    bool Result { set; get; }
    string EngineErrorMessage { set; get; }
}

public class MyClass1 : ISerializationErrorWriter
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    public bool Result { get; set; }
    public string EngineErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2 : ISerializationErrorWriter
{
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }

    public bool Result { get; set; }
    public string EngineErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

// Option 1:
public void Serialization_1<T>(ref T engine) where T : ISerializationErrorWriter
{
    try
    {
        //Do some work with passed class
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        engine.Result = false;
        engine.EngineErrorMessage = e.Message;
    }
}

// Option 2:
public void Serialization_2<T>(ref T engine)
{
    try
    {
        //Do some work with passed class
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var serializationErrorWriter = engine as ISerializationErrorWriter;
        if(serializationErrorWriter != null)
        {
            serializationErrorWriter.Result = false;
            serializationErrorWriter.EngineErrorMessage = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make much difference here, but one of the properties was `MyProperty1`, not 2

Comment: It would have mattered more if you had used the property in `ISerializationErrorWriter`, but you didn't - so all is good.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use reflection at some point, via `typeof(T)` (or maybe `engine.GetType()`). If this is a frequent code-path you may want to cache some kind of strategy per-type to avoid overhead. Or perhaps better: use a pre-built serialization API that optimises for this type of scenario (i.e. most of them).

If you mean the `Result` and `EngineErrorMessage`, then 2 options:

1. put those two properties on an interface, implement that interface from the t 2 types, and add the `where T : ISomeInterface` constraint to `Serialization<T>`
2. use `dynamic` to duck-type to the properties

Answer (score -1):

If you have only two classes to deal with I think following serialization code can server you well

```
//The method is used to serialize classes above, classes are passed as generic types
                public void Serialization<T>(ref T engine)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Type genericType = typeof(T);

                        if (typeof(MyClass1).Equals(genericType))
                        {
                            MyClass1 engineClass1 = engine as MyClass1;
                            //DO something for class 1
                        }
                        else if (typeof(MyClass2).Equals(genericType))
                        {
                            MyClass2 engineClass2 = engine as MyClass2;
                            //DO something for class 2
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //If Exception occurs I would like to write values to passed class properties, how to do that?
                        Result = false;
                        EngineErrorMessage = e.Message;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question. The OP wanted to know how to write the properties `Result` and `EngineErrorMessage` in the `catch` block.

Comment: ohk.. sorry.. I misunderstood the question.